# Rename nested column names in R

Tags: r, json, nested

I am looking to create a json file based on a defined schema:

```
col1,
col2,
fields{name, value}
```

I have a data frame with four columns (col1 to col4) and am wanting to nest col3 and col4 into "field" and nest the column and the value for col3 and col4.

I have tried the following but have not be able to achieve the nesting that I am looking for:

```
df <- data.frame(
  col1 = c(seq(1, 5)),
  col2 = c(seq(6, 10)),
  col3 = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
  col4 = c(seq(100, 104))
) |>
  nest(fields = c(col3, col4))

# format to json
cat(rjson::toJSON(unname(split(df, 1:nrow(df)))))
```

How would I map and rename so that col3 and col4 are nested into "fields", where the first record has name equal to `name(col3)` and value equal to `col3` and the second record has name equal to `name(col4)` and value equal to `col4` that would return something like:

```
{
  "col1":1,
  "col2":6,
  "fields":[
    {
      "name":"col3",
      "value":"a"
    },
    {
      "name":"col4",
      "value":"q"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `pivot_longer` on each nested frame. (I'm slicing `1:2` just for reduced presentation here.)

```r
df %>%
  slice(1:2) %>%
  mutate(
    fields = lapply(fields, function(onefield) {
      mutate(onefield, across(everything(), as.character)) %>%
        pivot_longer(everything())
    })
  ) %>%
  jsonlite::toJSON(pretty = TRUE)
# [
#   {
#     "col1": 1,
#     "col2": 6,
#     "fields": [
#       {
#         "name": "col3",
#         "value": "a"
#       },
#       {
#         "name": "col4",
#         "value": "100"
#       }
#     ]
#   },
#   {
#     "col1": 2,
#     "col2": 7,
#     "fields": [
#       {
#         "name": "col3",
#         "value": "b"
#       },
#       {
#         "name": "col4",
#         "value": "101"
#       }
#     ]
#   }
# ]
```

You can easily use `purrr::map` instead of `lapply` if you prefer, it changes nothing.

Note that this has to convert `104` to `"104"` (etc), since reshaping requires all values to share the same class. This means that some of your entries are (e.g.) `"value": "104"`.

Comment: This does exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much of your help!